# I have Ubuntu 10.10 and I am trying to upgrade to newest LTS

Tags: upgrade, 10.10

I am running a laptop with Windows 7 / Ubuntu 10.10 (I believe it is 10.10) and I need help upgrading my 10.10 to the newest LTS.

Please give me step by step as I am not very familiar with updating operating systems. I do no know many computer technical terms, I have a more than basic understanding but nothing in depth.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: There is no direct upgrade path, you would have to hop from 10.10 to 11.04* -> 11.10* -> 12.04* LTS, then you can do LTS jumps to 14.04 LTS -> 16.04 LTS. This results in a total of 5 upgrades, where 4 of them start from an old, unsupported release (*), which makes it an extra bit difficult. You should really consider backing up all data and doing a complete fresh reinstall. It will be faster, easier, and result in a more stable and better performing system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't jump from 10.10 to the last LTS version (16.04), not to mention you are running an outdated version which has no support at all.

Get a backup of your files, do a fresh install of 16.04.

And here is a [guide to update Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu#110483).

Comment: This is the most realistic action for any unexperienced user, or any experienced one with that wishes to keep his/her sanity.